# POST multipart/form-data with Guzzle 4

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 4 and I want to POST files with multipart/form-data. I'm not sure which is the right way to do this.

I've tried:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'https://127.0.0.1/1/files/', ['json' => ['id' => 'dc51bfe4-92af-483d-80c4-f2da4cafa723'], 'cookies' => true]);

$request->getBody()->addFile(new PostFile('a.pdf', fopen('a.pdf', 'rb')));
$response = $this->client->send($request);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream::addFile()
```

The same happens if I replace addFile with addPostFile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used Guzzle, but I tried this code out and was able to fix it by replacing

```
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'https://127.0.0.1/1/files/', ['json' => ['id' => 'dc51bfe4-92af-483d-80c4-f2da4cafa723'], 'cookies' => true]);
```

with this

```
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'https://127.0.0.1/1/files/', ['cookies' => true]);
```

You can probably pass the json data after the createRequest. You should check the Guzzle documentation for that.

Also, you seem to be using both `$client` and `$this->client`. I think you probably should just stick to one of the two.

Comment: Ah thanks. But I can't find how to pass the json data afterwards. I found setBody() but that is for Guzzle v3, not v4.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you need to do. I find it a bit strange that you want to post JSON data (probably application/json content-type), along with a file (probably multipart/form-data content-type). I think you may want to simply pass the id field using `$request->getBody()->setFields`